# .htaccess redirect/rewrite from one url to another, and subpages to other pages

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having some difficulty trying to get a correct rewrite/redirect that will do what I want and I'm wondering if it's even possible.

I have this rewrite setup:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This works great to take all requests from olddomain.com/whatever and rewrite them to my new main url. However, I also would like to be able to take 10 or 15 of the most popular "old" urls and rewrite/redirect them to the new location on the new url. My directory structure changed with the changeover to new url, so all the new urls are different and things are located in different places. Is it possible to have all traffic from the old domain redirected to the new domain AND specify a few old urls to redirect to new urls on the new domain?

I hope this is clear enough and I'm hoping someone can assist me. Thanks for your time!

Tom

Comment: Sure that is possible. You just single pick those specific urls and rewrite them _before_ you make the catch-all rule you posted above. So in a way you implement exceptions to be handled first. This way you can rewrite specific urls any specific way you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

**.htaccess for old domain**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In the above, you could place redirect rules to catch certain pages and forward them to their new location, like this:

```
Redirect 301 /2012/05/old-post http://www.newdomain.com/old-post
```

Be sure to place the redirect directives above the rewrite rule that catches everything else.

**.htaccess for new domain**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.[a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6} [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$     [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Found this solution on: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/htaccess-redirect-all-traffic-to-another-site.867280/

I've done similar things, so hopefully it helps.